# fixed header html table with bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I have a html table with bootstrap styling and I trying to make it as fixed-header table which is given in [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/pgosxkrm/5/). But the columns are misaligned between header and body of the table.

I tried with

```
$fixedColumn.find('thead').find('tr:first').find('th').each(function (i, elem) {
    var w = $table.find('tbody').find('tr:first').find('td:eq(' + i + ')').width();
     $(this).css({width: w});  
});
```

But no use. How can I set the exact width of the columns to the fixed header columns?

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/139/ (pure bootstrap, no plugin)

i used two tables, one for the header, one for the body. i applied css to the div around the body to create the overflow. then minor styles on the top header to get the header borders to align. hope this helps!

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-right:21px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Top Header</th>
                <th>Top Header</th>
                <th>Top Header</th>
                <th>Top Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 scroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
                <td>Normal Cell</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

.scroll {
    height:100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes... similar to your example. But I trying to clone the parent table itself instead of two separate tables. Also in your sample, The vertical borders are slightly misaligned between table body and table head.